# Button selector pressed_state doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a different style for pressed button but it doesn't work. (Default style works.) This is complete code. Please can you see the issue.

Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="???"
        android:background="@drawable/button_generic"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"> <!--Android ignores this :-/ -->
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#adadad" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#e8e8e8" />
            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#adadad" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Activity

```
public class TActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.t);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either:

- adding these 2 properties to your `Button` in xml:

`android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"`

- or adding `View.OnClickListener` to your `Button` programatically in `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

*How I understand, you want to make some changes when button is clicked, alright? In your code when user clicked on button it will change background color to red.

If it is question, in your code you just have problem with*

```
android:text="???"
```

convert that to

```
android:text="sometext"
```

It will work 100%

[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzCH3.jpg)

[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNhX6.jpg)

I put two picture how it work with your code, I just change "???" to "AAA".

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help.

Comment: @BJ yesterday I try it and it work correctly, I try it on physical device "Samsung Galaxy S6". Which error/problem android studio show to you?

Comment: I'm testing it on emulator API 27. I didn't get any error, it just didn't work.

Comment: @BJ Check answer now, please let me know if it is what you want